# Какой знак лучше выбрать и как объяснить?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, грамматика, тире, бсп

Из современной литературы:

*Мама спокойно слушает. Язык, как известно, тоже мышца. **Ребёночек поболтал утром, кровь в мозг прилила (?) вроде как зарядку сделал.** После зарядки авось дотащится до ванной и до кухни. А там можно покормить и дружелюбным пинком отослать в школу.*

Предложение с виду простое, но как объяснить **грамматику** и выбрать знак препинания? Можно отметить нестандартный **порядок** трех частей сообщения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ребёночек поболтал утром, кровь в мозг прилила – вроде как зарядку сделал.*

Ставим тире. В книге «[Последний стожар](https://www.livelib.ru/book/643105/readpart-eva-i-magicheskie-suschestva-poslednij-stozhar-dmitrij-emets/%7E5)» (Дмитрий Емец) так и есть.
Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (***вроде как*** – частица, см. [Грамота.ру](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&mode=slovari)).

Сюда в той или иной степени подходят сразу три пункта параграфа Розенталя «[Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151)».

> **3.** Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится **тире**, если в ней содержится *следствие, результат* либо *вывод* из того, о чем говорится в первой части (между частями можно вставить слова *поэтому, тогда* и т. п.).

*Поболтал, кровь прилила – [поэтому, тогда, можно сказать] зарядку сделал.*

> **5.** Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится **тире**, если в первой части обозначается *условие* совершения действия, о котором говорится во второй части (в начале первой части можно добавить союз *если*).

*[Если] поболтал – зарядку сделал.*

> **6.** Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится **тире**, если в ней содержится *сравнение* с тем, о чем говорится в первой части (перед второй частью можно добавить союз *словно* или *будто*).

***Вроде как*** уже имеет значение ***как будто, кажется, словно***.

*Поболтал – [будто] зарядку сделал.*

**P. S.** Запятая вместо тире, на мой взгляд, здесь не смотрится, так как чувствуется явная взаимообусловленность частей предложения, и это хочется подчеркнуть интонационно.

Answer (score 2):

**Комментарий к ответу**

Спасибо за ответ! У меня были такие **проблемы.**

1. Я не считала, что это ***БСП.*** Видела **однородные** члены: *поболтал, вроде как зарядку сделал*. А между ними отдельное предложение. Структура показалась странной, а в этом случае я обычно решаю методом **блоков.** Третья часть — **присоединительная** конструкция, но тесно связанная с основным содержанием: Запятой мало, единый знак не подойдет, получается **тире**.

Но вы обошлись без блоков, поэтому интересно было **сравнить** два решения. Результат одинаковый, а методики разные.

2. ***Вроде как*** — союз или частица? Считала **союзом**, поэтому не получалось БСП. Сейчас смотрю **у Ефремовой:**

**Вроде как.** **I союз разг.** Употребляется при присоединении члена предложения или части предложения (в которых выражается **приблизительное сходство)**, соответствуя по значению сл.: как будто, словно, будто. **II част. разг.** 1. Употребляется при выражении **неуверенности или предположительности** высказывания, соответствуя по значению сл.: по-видимому, вероятно, наверное. 2. Употребляется при выражении **условной предположительности** высказывания, соответствуя по значению сл.: как бы, будто бы.

Наверное, **без разницы.**

Еще раз спасибо!

P.S. **О книге**

**Еве 14 лет,**  ей надо  в школу,  а времени вечно не хватает.  Вот она торопливо обулась, схватила рюкзак, куртку и выскочила на улицу. Был ясный солнечный день, но Ева желтыми листьями не любовалась – она неслась… навстречу удивительным событиям.

**Герои любимых книг** — как лучшие друзья. Их мир не менее реален, чем мир обыкновенный. К ним заходишь, чтобы навестить их  —  как бы ты с ними, но просто невидим. И все события можно пережить **заново**, будто и не знаешь, что их ждет.

Когда читаешь книгу первый раз, то  увлекаешься **сюжетом.**  И только потом уже интересна **художественная форма**, лексика, грамматика.  Грамматика — особенно!  Есть синтаксис совершенно **необыкновенный**, в учебниках такого не найдешь.

Comment: Да, спасибо! "...как бы ты с ними, но просто невидим" – да, это так. А мне даже снилось несколько раз, что я нахохусь среди героев книг или фильмов, разговариваю с ними... //  А методом блоков я бы предпочёл решать более сложные конструкции.

Comment: Про сны интересно!  Мне бы такие посмотреть!   Говорят, что сны можно заказывать, но не знаю, как и где) // Я тоже не все решаю блоками, только сомнительную для меня грамматику.